# Python - How to add then limit a number in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I assume the title is not really clear so I shall show it

```
py -= move_speed
if py <= 5:
   py = 5
```

So, essentially I am asking how to limit the numbers from adding higher than five. If it is bigger than five, stop the adding and then keep it at five

The code I am wanting to implement this to is this

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
    y -= move_speed
    py -= move_speed
    if py <= 5:
        py = 5
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You already have it. What's the problem

Comment: When I implement this, the program will keep it at five, even if I want it to go back to 0. Sorry, I am not good at describing somethings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only shorter way than what you've got would be to do something like this:

```
py = max(py - movespeed, 5)
```

Note that this matches your code but not your description. You seem to be describing doing this the other way around - ie,

```
py = min(py + movespeed, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the description of trying to make sure `py` does not go over `5`, I think you have a bug here:

```
if py <= 5:
    py = 5
```

You probably meant to write

```
if py >= 5:
    py = 5
```

However, your code is doing `-=`, so the other bound makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to *clamp* a value between two numbers, I think a minimum of 0 and a maximum of 5:

```
py = max(0, min(py, 5))
```